# WPF TextBlock binding to ResourceDictionary in mutilingual

Tags: c#, wpf, multilingual, resourcedictionary

I have a mutilingual wpf project. I am using ResourceDictionary to do this. For static `TextBlock` I can change the Text language by:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Sample, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" />
```

**BUT** how should I change a dynamic `TextBlock` Text. It seems impossible to do it in this way:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Sample}
```

And in the code behind:

```
Sample = Resources.SampleText;
```

If this is impossible. Is there any other options? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class where the `Sample` property is define should implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and raise change notifications:

```
public class Translations : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _sample;
    public string Sample
    {
        get { return _sample; }
        set { _sample = value; OnPropertyChanged("Sample"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Only then you will be able to update the `TextBlock` dynamically by simply setting the `Sample` source property to a new `string` value.